# Astropy not working in Anaconda IPython on Windows

Tags: python, ipython, anaconda, astropy

I am using Anaconda Python. If I just enter `python` environment the `astropy` works okay.

But if I enter the `IPython` environment (NOT THE IPYTHON NOTEBOOK where it obviously does not work), this astropy does not load.

On typing `from astropy.io import fits`, the error is :

> DLL load failed: %1 is not a valid Win32 application.

On entering `import astropy`, it says :

> Cannot import name config

So, what is the problem? I really do not have any idea.

```
EDIT:
```

Ok. Now it works in `ipython` and `notebook` apart from just `python` after I start worknig from the `scripts` folder only.
But I have to do that every time ! Else, it does not work. :( 
Error shown is:

> cannot import name config

[image]

Comment: Did you try and install Astropy yourself, or are you using the version that shops with Anaconda?

Comment: tried both. i mean latest what i did was install astropy after having installed anaconda before

Comment: Maybe the IPython isn't the one from Anaconda. What is `sys.prefix` within `ipython` (vs. `python`)?

Comment: Pasting the full traceback (or screenshot if you can't select the text) would be much more helpful than just the error message.

Comment: Likely duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20426690/pyfits-not-working-for-windows-64-bit